# Setting up Wordpress with Xampp on Mac

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, macos, xampp

I am trying to get Wordpress working locally on my Mac. I've downloaded and installed Xampp and also the Wordpress module. But I'm not sure where to go from here, to actually get Wordpress working.

When I try to reach 127.0.0.1/wordpress/ and localhost/wordpress/ I only get the message "Error establishing a database connection".

I can reach PhpMyAdmin, enclosing a screenshot.

[Screenshot from phpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTKO8.png)

I have no clue where to go from here. Do I need to make changes in some conf-files or something? This is the first time I'm doing this so sorry for noob questions, I'm not really a programmer, just want to be able to build my Wordpress sites locally... :)

Comment: What's in your `wp-config.php` file?

Comment: Have you checked the wp-config.php? Specially "DB_NAME", "DB_USER" and "DB_PASSWORD".

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a database within PHPMyAdmin, and then configure wp-config.php with the database information. By default, you may only have a file called wp-config-sample.php. Rename the file, and remove -sample from the file name.

The host name will be "localhost", since the database is locally hosted.

The username will be the username to phpmyadmin, and the password will be the password for that account.

The database name will be the database name that you chose.

The prefix can be left alone, as the default is just fine. :)

Comment: Ok I will try that, thanks!

But another thing I discovered is that all the Wordpress files are located in Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apps/wordpress/conf/htdocs and this folder was protected from even viewing, I had to change that. And it seems that all files in this folder (including wp-config.php) are also write protected. Is this the way it should be?

Comment: This is in my wp-config.php right now (I changed the rights on this file because I couldn't even open it)

`// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'bitnami_wordpress');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'bn_wordpress');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'ea2ae44234');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:3306');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');`

Comment: I'd recommend removing the password from your comment, for your own safety. :) Furthermore, the location of the files appears odd. Did you install Wordpress through some form of a tool, or did you download the ZIP and unpack it? In any case, the file seems okay, but you don't necessarily need the :3306 in the DB_HOST property. :)

Comment: I downloaded Bitnami Wordpress Module.

Comment: I had a look in phpMyAdmin, and there is a database there called bitnami_wordpress. Username bn_wordpress exists and the wp-config.php contains this:

`/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'bitnami_wordpress');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'bn_wordpress');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'ea2ae44234');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');`

Where can I check the password in the database?

Comment: You can confirm that the username and password works at your phpmyadmin login page. :) It sounds like it should work though, because I think that bitnami handles the whole installation for you.

Comment: But I still get the "Error establishing a database connection" message when trying to reach localhost/wordpress. How can I confirm the password? In wp-config.php I can see that DB_NAME and DB_USER are correct according to what I see in phpMyAdmin, but where can I confirm the DB_PASSWORD?

Comment: @MarkusP Of course. :) You mentioned that you have access to phpmyadmin, right? If so, you can try the username, and password at that login screen.